# How would you explain this query in layman terms?

Tags: sql, exists

Here is the database I'm using: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ArJekOQpal0JFIr1h3NXYcFVngnCNUxg/view?usp=sharing

```
select distinct 
    AC1.givename, AC1.famname, AC2.givename, AC2.famname
from 
    academic AC1, author AU1, academic AC2, author AU2
where 
    AC1.acnum = AU1.acnum
    and AC2.acnum = AU2.acnum
    and AU1.panum = AU2.panum
    and AU2.acnum > AU1.acnum
    and not exists (select *
                    from Interest I1, Interest I2
                    where I1.acnum = AC1.acnum
                      and I2.acnum = AC2.acnum);
```

Output:
[image: Output]
I'm having trouble explaining this output of the subquery and query in layman terms(Normal english).

Not sure if my explanation is right:

"The subquery finds the interested fields where two authors have no common field of interest.

The whole query finds the first and last names of the authors of papers which have at least two authors, and have no common field of interest."

Comment: I don't think the query makes a great deal of sense. The subquery fails to do anything relating `I1` to `I2`. Of course, the intent of the query *might* be clearer if whoever authored it caught up with the ANSI-1992 version of the SQL language and use explicit joins rather than comma joins. I know, they've only had *a quarter of a century* to pick up on this :-(

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: You say "no common field of interest".  Then I'm guessing that the NOT EXISTS should also join on I1.FIELD = I2.FIELD

Answer (score 0):

As it currently stands, the subquery will produce rows if each academic has at least one interest.

So overall, the query is "produce pairs of academics who co-authored at least one paper and where at least one of them has no interests whatsoever". It's difficult to believe that that was the intent, and if it was, there are clearer ways of writing it that make it more clear that that is what we're looking for.

If that's the query we want, though, I'd write it as:

```
SELECT
    AC1.givename, AC1.famname, AC2.givename, AC2.famname
FROM
    academic AC1
       inner join
    academic AC2
       on
          AC1.acnum < AC2.acnum
WHERE EXISTS
    (select * from author au1 inner join author au2 on au1.panum = au2.panum
     where au1.acnum = ac1.acnum and au2.acnum = ac2.acnum)
AND
    (
    NOT EXISTS (select * from interest i where i.acnum = ac1.acnum)
    OR
    NOT EXISTS (select * from interest i where i.acnum = ac2.acnum)
    )
```

If, as is more likely, we wanted pairs of co-authors who have no interests *in common*, we would write something like:

```
SELECT
    AC1.givename, AC1.famname, AC2.givename, AC2.famname
FROM
    academic AC1
       inner join
    academic AC2
       on
          AC1.acnum < AC2.acnum
WHERE EXISTS
    (select * from author au1 inner join author au2 on au1.panum = au2.panum
     where au1.acnum = ac1.acnum and au2.acnum = ac2.acnum)
AND NOT EXISTS
    (select * from interest i1 inner join interest i2 on i1.field = i2.field
     where i1.acnum = ac1.acnum and i2.acnum = ac2.acnum)
```

Notice how neither of my queries uses `distinct`, because we've made sure that the outer query isn't *joining* additional rows where we only care about the *existence* or *absence* of those rows - we've moved all such checks into `EXISTS` subqueries.

I generally see `distinct` used far too often when the author is getting multiple results when they only want a single result and they're unwilling to expend the effort to discover *why* they're getting multiple results. In this case, it would be situations where the same pairs of academics have co-authored more than one paper.